# Is it possible to have both Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication in an ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a site where the vast majority of the content will be secured using Forms Authentication.  However there is one sub folder that will be used internally by the administrative staff.  I would like to secure this folder using Windows Authentication.  Is that possible?  Would I have to make the admin folder a virtual directory?

CLARIFICATION:  There is no need for the administrative staff to access the main site.  They are really two separate sites/apps.  Regular users will access the main application via Forms Authentication (and never access the admin folder).  And admin users will access the admin application via Windows Authentication (and never access the main site).

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you have to build a custom membership provider or an interface to allow for it. It is not possible to specify individual authentication methods on sub-folders unless they are in completely separate projects/application domains.

One method to accomplish this would be to use an LDAP membership provider and change the ldap connection based on the username (if there is a discernible method of doing this).

One other method would be to provide a separate website that uses the Windows authentication to perform the login and then constructs a custom cookie for the user and transfers them back to the original website identifying the individual as a member of the administrative staff.

Then the folder could be secured using the `<location>` elements in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to build a site with Mixed authentication, I would setup the site to use webforms. I would then setup a virtual application inside of this application that consisted of the same forms auth web.config information but set to use Windows Auth.

On the login page of the windows auth site after you validate their credentials I would then manually call FormsAuthentication to create the auth token. At this point you can then redirect the user to the Forms Auth site and they should be logged in (as long as all the forms auth cookie information is the same for both sites, this might also include needing to setup the same machine keys for both applications).

I haven't done this specifically but this should definitely be a viable (and probably one of the most optimal) solutions.

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't clarify this in my initial question.  There really is no need for the admin users who are logging in to the admin application via Windows Authentication to have access to the rest of the site (and vice versa).  They are really two completely separate sites/applications.  Maybe a better way to describe it is that I have a Forms Authentication that will have one folder that will be accessed by admin users using Windows Authentication and the admin users do not need access to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as right-clicking on the admin folder in Windows Explorer and setting the rights in the Security tab.

Answer (score 0):

Put the administration site in its own application - by right clicking on the folder in IIS manager and and choose convert to application.

Once that's done you can adjust the authentication method on the application by highlighting the application folder in IIS manager and then choosing authentication and adjusting them (or you can do it the hard way via web.config if you can't remote into the machine).